# WCF XmlNode : Can't serialize

Tags: .net, wcf, c#-4.0

I am rewriting a legacy asp.net web service (.asmx) in WCF. The legacy service exposed a method argument of type XmlNode. Seems like in WCF the XmlNode type cannot be serialized. If i try to change the arg to a string on the service side the consumer (.net class library service host wrapper) which is expecting XmlNode complains and does not execute successfully. I cannot change the service host. Any insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace it with `XmlElement` or `XElement`. ASMX services could return `XmlNode`, but not all subclasses of it were supported - for example, if you tried to return a `XmlAttribute`, it would fail. If you're already returning `XmlElement`, then you're fine; if you're returning a `XmlDocument`, then you can change it to return the `DocumentElement` its property (which is a `XmlElement`).